# Where can I find Hpricot documentation?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

Now that http://github.com/why/hpricot/wikis/home no longer exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try for [github.com/whymirror](http://github.com/whymirror) you will get everything created by _why

or specifically https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/wiki for Hpricot